# Java REGEX XML parse/cut-down while maintaining structure HowTo

Tags: java, xml, regex

I am writing a RESTful web service in Java.
The idea is to "cut down" an XML document and strip away all the unneeded content (~98%) and leave only the tags we're interested in, while maintaining the document's structure, which is as follows (I cannot provide the actual XML content for confidentiality reasons):

```
<sear:SEGMENTS xmlns="http://www.exlibrisgroup.com/xsd/primo/primo_nm_bib" xmlns:sear="http://www.exlibrisgroup.com/xsd/jaguar/search">
   <sear:JAGROOT>
      <sear:RESULT>
         <sear:DOCSET IS_LOCAL="true" TOTAL_TIME="176" LASTHIT="9" FIRSTHIT="0" TOTALHITS="262" HIT_TIME="11">
            <sear:DOC SEARCH_ENGINE_TYPE="Local Search Engine" SEARCH_ENGINE="Local Search Engine" NO="1" RANK="0.086826384" ID="2347460">
               [
               <PrimoNMBib>
                  <record>
                     <display>
                        <title></title>
                     </display>
                     <sort>
                        <author></author>
                     </sort>
                  </record>
               </PrimoNMBib>
               ]
            </sear:DOC>
         </sear:DOCSET>
      </sear:RESULT>
   </sear:JAGROOT>
</sear:SEGMENTS>
```

Of course, this is the structure of only the tags we are interested in - there are hundreds more tags, but they are irrelevant.

The square brackets (`[]`) are not part of the XML and indicate that the element `<PrimoNMBib></PrimoNMBib>` are elements of a list of children and occur more than once - one per match of the search from the RESTFUL service.

I've been trying to parse the document with regular expressions, as to leave only the segments of the structure as shown above along with the values of `<title>` and `<author>` while removing everything else in-between the tags including other tags, however I can't get it to work for the life of me...

Previously I tried it using XSLT, however for unresolved reasons that didn't work either... I'd already asked a question for the XSLT implementation...

Anyway, I would very much appreciate a tip/hint/solution as how to solve this problem using regex and Java...

Comment: I'm sorry to hear XSLT, which is designed for exactly this, doesn't work for you.  Doing it with regular expressions sounds very hard.  In fact, doing it any other way than using an XML parsing library sounds hard.  Perhaps something like making a [SAXParser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) and building up a stack of the ancestor tags might help?

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob. Perhaps you would be able to suggest how one could tackle this with XSLT? perhaps you would be able to suggest something for my XSLT implementation?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340023/restful-glassfish-xml-xslt-stylesheet-java-transformation-produces-empty-output

Comment: If is guaranteed the tags to be each one on a separated line and that removing the unnecessary tags will not brake validity of xml structure, you could use a script (perl, bash, sed, python, etc) using regex to read the lines and strip the ones that not contain required tags openings and endings.

Comment: So I did go look at that question.  You said you transformed it via a browser - does that mean you've run that same XSLT transformation successfully on the same documents outside your Java code?  If so, it sounds like an XSLT "engine" difference.  Wild guess - try inserting the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the front of your Java string.

Comment: Hi Rob, yes, I put <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?> at the beginning of my xml where test.xsl is the stylesheet, and applied it in google chrome and it worked just fine... by java string, do you mean my xml string or xsl string?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using regex to manipulate XML.

**Alternative Approach**

You could use a StAX parser that leverages a `StreamFilter` to cut down the document and still maintain a valid structure.

**How a `StreamFilter` Works**

A `StreamFilter` receives event event from the `XMLStreamReader`, if you want to have the event reported you return true, otherwise false.  In the example below the `StreamFilter` will reject anything in the `"http://www.exlibrisgroup.com/xsd/jaguar/search"` namespace.  You will need to tweak the logic to get it to match the requirements of your use case.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/StreamFilter.html

***Demo***

```
package forum10351473;

import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.xml.stream.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("src/forum10351473/input.xml"));
        xsr = xif.createFilteredReader(xsr, new StreamFilter() {

            private boolean reportContent = false;

            @Override
            public boolean accept(XMLStreamReader reader) {
                if(reader.isStartElement() || reader.isEndElement()) {
                    reportContent = !"http://www.exlibrisgroup.com/xsd/jaguar/search".equals(reader.getNamespaceURI());
                }
                return reportContent;
            }

        });

        // The XMLStreamReader (xsr) will now only report the events you care about.
        // You can process the XMLStreamReader yourself or pass as input to something
        // like JAXB.
        while(xsr.hasNext()) {
            if(xsr.isStartElement()) {
                System.out.println(xsr.getLocalName());
            }
            xsr.next();
        }
    }

}
```

***Output***

```
PrimoNMBib
record
display
title
sort
author
```

Comment: Hi Blaise, thanks very much for the tip! How would I go about including the elements parent to PrimoNMBib also? :)

Comment: You want to include `sear:DOC` as well?  This can all be controlled in the `accept` method.  You just need to add the logic of when to accept/reject events.

Comment: Yes, I want to include all the parent tags including <sear:SEGMENTS ...> along with the text values of <title> and <author>. Can you help? :)

Comment: You just need to play around with the logic in the `accept` method to get the behaviour that you are looking for.

Comment: how do i do that though? i'm very confused as to how the method works... :(

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit, I think once you try to use it, it will become clearer.

Comment: The only thing i see different in the answer is the link to the api, which i've read before... I am still not sure how to choose which tags and which tag values to choose... Please help, thanks... I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Piotr In `accept()`, Mr Doughan is using `XMLStreamReader.getNamespaceURI()` and comparing it to the namespace in the input XML. If you would rather select by XML element name, there is also a `XMLStreamReader.getName()` method you can use to compare with a whitelist like this: `return setOfElementsICareAbout.contains(reader.getName());`

Comment: @Matt: hmmm... but how can i define the elements in the whitelist? would you be able to provide an example so that i'd be able to get the elements in the output format <tag>value</tag> where tag is in the white list? thanks so much! :)

Comment: @Piotr In that case, replace `!"http://www.exlibrisgroup.com/xsd/jaguar/search".equals(reader.getNamespaceURI())` in the answer's code with `"tag".equals(reader.getLocalName())`. And play around with XmlStreamReader's methods to do what you want; look at its documentation. We're here to answer your questions, but not to write your application. Just whatever you do, _do not attempt XML parsing via RegEx._